# Symfony2 BinaryFileResponse returns FileNotFound

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to make file download route in Symfony2. My code

```
if(!file_exists($w->getOrgUrlFullPath())) {
     return new Response('File not exists');
}
    $response = new BinaryFileResponse($w->getOrgUrlFullPath());
    //These doesn't work
    BinaryFileResponse::trustXSendfileTypeHeader();
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/zip');
    $response->setContentDisposition(
        ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        'file.zip'
    );
    return $response;
```

Files are located i non public directory (upper) for being available only by this controller, but when I check file for exists everything is ok, when I try download file as `DISPOSITION_INLINE` code outputs me contents of file.
But when I try to download file as `DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT`, browser returns me "File cannot be found" - it comes from browser, not from Symfony.

Can anyone help me?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that file size is ~300 mb

EDIT2: OK, I found that problem is size of file, for smaller files its working well. But for larger it returns empty content. Its not readed on the fly?

Comment: Have you tried with a StreamedResponse instead ? http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#streaming-a-response

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but it returns me empty content. I dont know why it wont work. I tried to return headers first and then return content, but after some time it breaks connection (php time limit on hosting). Might it be hosting related?